# C++ function local SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, c++03

I have an error reporting system, where non-configured errors shall be ignored (configured just means there is a typedef for the given error). So at the places where something is reported it should become a NOP, if the typedef is missing.

The problem is that I want to generate a SFINAE expression locally to be able to write something like (it is a work in progress, please ignore naming and so on):

Oh. And sorry. It has to be C++03/98 compliant. Silly embedded compilers...

```
// Error.h
template<uint32_t ID>
struct Error {  enum { value = ID };  };

enum { IGNORE_UNKNOWN = 1, DISALLOW_UNKNOWN = 2 };

// TheConfig.h
namespace config {
struct TheConfig {
    typedef Error<1> Error1;
    typedef Error<2> Error2;
    enum { MISSING_ERROR_POLICY = IGNORE_UNKNOWN };
};
}

// ErrorReport.h
template<typename T>
struct ReportEvent {
    inline void operator()() {
        T event;
        std::cout << "Called with error event" << event.value << std::endl;
    }
};

struct IgnoreEvent {
    inline void operator()() {
        std::cout << "Event ignored" << std::endl;
    }
};

// The magic macro defining a magic SFINAE 
#define REPORT_ERROR(event_name) \
    ....


// Usage
int f() {
    REPORT_ERROR(Error1);  // Reports the error
    REPORT_ERROR(Error5);  // Is a NOP as it is not configured
}
```

My current implementation unfortunately gives me (in visual studio) C2951 : "type declarations are only permitted at global, namespace, or class scope". But moving in into a sub dummy class just gives C2892 : "local class shall not have member templates".

```
#define REPORT_ERROR(event_name) \
    { \
        template<typename T> struct void_type { \
            typedef void type; \
            enum { exists = false }; \
        }; \
        template<typename T, typename = void> \
        struct type_if_exists_##event_name : void_type<void> {}; \
        template<typename T> \
        struct type_if_exists_##event_name<T, typename void_type<typename T::event_name>::type>  \
        { \
            typedef typename T::event_name type; \
            enum { exists = true }; \
        }; \
    static_assert(config::TheConfig::MISSING_ERROR_POLICY == IGNORE_UNKNOWN || \
        type_if_exists_##event_name<config::TheConfig>::exists, \
        "COM event " #event_name " can be reportet, but is not configured."); \
    std::conditional<type_if_exists_##event_name<config::TheConfig>::exists, \
        ReportEvent<type_if_exists_##event_name<config::TheConfig>::type>, \
        IgnoreEvent>::type()() \
}
```

Is there any way I can create these SFINAE expressions locally and not having to move the generation into the global scope?

Comment: I don't think so as templates must be namespace or class scoped.  They cannot be function scoped.

Comment: Maybe you could create a namespace reserved for only such uses. It'd still be globally "visible", but at least wouldn't lead to collisions.

Comment: This may be an XY problem. The real problem is to find a macro such that `REPORT_ERROR(X)` expands to legal code inside a function, with the exact result depending on whether  `DEFINE_ERROR(X)` has previously appeared at global scope. SFINAE is just one method. It fails because local template definitions are illegal. Using `X` to declare a function might be more fruitful; functions can be declared locally.

Comment: Yes. I was just hoping I was missing some method of creating new SFINAE expressions, that can be created inside a class/function.